# How can I use jQuery from TypeScript with VS2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

**NOTE**: this is a question about Visual Studio **2017**. Answers or advice relating to earlier versions are likely to be *un*helpful. Thanks.

---

I'm utterly at my wit's end. I've been trying to get a simple Visual Studio 2017 web project to work using TypeScript (v2.3), and it's so stupidly frustrating that it has left me exhausted and enraged. I truly doubt that anyone has ever accomplished this feat without abandoning the Visual Studio tooling and setting everything up outside/alongside VS.

My first problem is that there are various resources on the web that suggest different ways to do this, and they all conflict: "use Gulp", "no, use Bower", "use NPM", "no, use WebPack". And of course much of the advice to be found relates to earlier versions of Visual Studio.

Similarly, the TypeScript syntax for importing modules seems to change with every version, so much of *that* advice is also out-of-date, and further depends on which module loader, etc. you're using.

Lots of options is "great", but the tooling must be at least *slightly* opinionated, and I can't figure out what the path of least resistance is. I'd like to stick with the stuff that MS have actually integrated with VS, since I'm really not a fan of command lines and config files when the commands and config formats change weekly.

I followed [the steps in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html) to create a web project that does little more than say "hello world", but stopped just before the section "Add Angular 2". (I don't want to use Angular, or at least not yet).

So, by this point I've got some **NuGet** dependencies, some **NPM** dependencies, and **package.json**, **tsconfig.json**, and **gulpfile.json** files.

What I want to do now is add jQuery to my project, and be able to say (in my TypeScript file):

```
let foo: JQuery = $("p");
```

So, I obviously need the jQuery library, and I need typescript definitions for jQuery. That should not be hard - but I, a developer of some 30 years standing, cannot figure out how to add those things using the new tooling.

I tried adding "jquery" as a dependency in the NPM package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.2.1"
},
```

... but I can't figure out how to add the corresponding typescript definitions.

The TypeScript manual suggests using `npm import @types/jquery` but I don't have an NPM command line, and when I tried adding that directly to the dependencies (or devDependencies) section in the **package.json** file, it didn't recognize it.

In yet another "tutorial" I found (this one using Bower just to make sure it was a little more confusing), it was suggested to add the following to the **tsconfig.json** file to enable automatic type aquisition for TypeScript, which *sounds* great:

```
"typeAcquisition": {
  "enable": true
},
```

But sadly that doesn't seem to work. Or at least, not with the setup I currently have. [While it did provide Intellisense within the IDE when I followed the steps in that other tutorial, I was never actually able to get the project to compile.]

So, here I am, begging for help. How can I get my one-line piece of TypeScript to (a) recognize the JQuery type definitions, and (b) actually compile and run?

Better yet, if anyone knows of any online resources that actually explain all this **for the current version of all the tools** then I'd love to see that. Otherwise I may just go back to VS2015.

Answer (score 6):

I had difficults with adding typing support to VS2017 but it looks like 15.4 update fix my problems.
First of all you should add `@types/jquery` devDependencies to your `package.json` file. For example:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "version": "0.0.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    /*other packages*/
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",        
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.47"
    /*other dev packages*/
  }
}
```

Than you should setup your `tsconfig.json` file. For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "jquery"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "scripthost",
      "es2015.iterable"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    //"outDir": "wwwroot/app-out"
    "outFile": "wwwroot/app-out/app.js"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

So I set `module` to `none` so it does not require to set up module bundler such as webpack for example. In types we should specify `jquery` which we specified early in `package.json`. Also we should specify `"dom", "es5", "scripthost", "es2015.iterable"` in `lib` because `@types/jquery` require it. `outFile` tell ts where to place compiled js file. So after that you can just add reference to it in your page.

After that jquery types start working in ts file without any further set up. Sometimes `tsconfig.json` file changes does not apply on fly. So make changes, download npm modules (rebuild solution for example) and then restart VS.

Comment: Well, thanks, that did move me forward a little, but then I had SO many other problems that I'm practically suicidal again. I never got it anywhere near working, and I almost can't bear even to look at my PC now because I'm so incredibly frustrated.

For so long I've defended Microsoft on the basis that if nothing else their tooling was always so good, but - this is a clusterf*ck. I'm not going to waste any more time on it.

Not your fault, though - and thanks anyway.

Comment: Having the same issues and appreciate the answer. But would like to hear from someone about using the tools provided in VS2017, nuget, npm, gulp, etc. What's the best practice?

Comment: what I tent to believe nowadays is that we use vs code for frontend development if we want to use any packaging technique together with front-end framework. and use vs 2017 for API stuff. in all other cases, I stick to mvc, razor and plain old js